# Wrong reference to figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

When I refer to figure in text, it will not appear in the text like number but like question mark.

```
Na obrázku \ref{slm-princip} je vidět princip funkce zařízení SLM. Vysokovýkonný laser je zaměřován pomocí natáčecích zrcadel. Po dokončení tavení vrstvy sjede ...

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\color{FigureColor}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{1.5pt}      
\captionbox{Princip výroby stroje SLM [12]}{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Obrazky/slm-princip.jpg}}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \label{slm-princip} }
 \end{figure}
```

[image]

If you need more details, please let me know.
Thank you

My packages are

```
\usepackage{inputenc}       
\usepackage{babel}     
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}    
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{indentfirst}            
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Where does `\captionbox` come from? (Complete examples, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228, is always preferrable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `\label` in the first argument, along with the caption, not the second, with the image.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
Na obrázku \ref{slm-princip} je vidět princip funkce zařízení SLM. Vysokovýkonný laser je zaměřován pomocí natáčecích zrcadel. Po dokončení tavení vrstvy sjede ...

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\color{blue}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{1.5pt}      
\captionbox{Princip výroby stroje SLM [12]\label{slm-princip}}{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image}}}
 \end{figure}  
\end{document}
```